# Unable to use JSONpath type querying

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, json.net

I'm using C# VS2012 with JSON.net. I'm trying to implement [this](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) simple example in my project.
Meanwhile I'm reading [this](http://www.codedisqus.com/0JxqgejkeX/using-filters-with-jsonpath-in-c.html) article which seems to be of a similar situation.

This is my code :

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

private void JSONpath_Tutorial()
{
    JObject o = JObject.Parse(@"{
    'Stores': [
    'Lambton Quay',
    'Willis Street'
    ],
    'Manufacturers': [
    {
      'Name': 'Acme Co',
      'Products': [
        {
          'Name': 'Anvil',
          'Price': 50
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      'Name': 'Contoso',
      'Products': [
        {
          'Name': 'Elbow Grease',
          'Price': 99.95
        },
        {
          'Name': 'Headlight Fluid',
          'Price': 4
        }
      ]
    }
    ]
    }");

    // manufacturer with the name 'Acme Co'
    JToken acme = o.SelectToken("$.Manufacturers[?(@.Name == 'Acme Co')]"); //getting error here

    Console.WriteLine(acme);
    // { "Name": "Acme Co", Products: [{ "Name": "Anvil", "Price": 50 }] }
}
```

I'm getting this exception here : `Unexpected character while parsing path indexer: ?`
Also, the `SelectTokens` method is not available in my intellisense. I'm really drawing a blank here. I've been trying for hours.

Comment: This [works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r2uDAz) for me. What version of JSON.NET are you using?

Comment: I'm using Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.11

Comment: [Here's the same code with 4.5.11](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r2uDAz)

Comment: [Here's](http://i.imgur.com/WOANLkP.png?1) the error I'm getting